# Cannot Find ToUpper in System

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I want to use the `string.ToUpper()` method in a .NET Standard Project that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netframework-4.8) says that the namespace should be System and that it should be compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 and Framework 4.6.1.

I have 7 projects in my solution and every Framework project has access to string.ToUpper except the Standard project. The Standard project has path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll for System and will not let me remove the reference or change the path. It seems that there is much more missing than ToUpper/ToLower however these are the only two methods I care about.

```
string str1 = "i need uppercase"; 
string upperCase = str1.ToUpper();
```

Comment: A list of things you want is not a question; do you have a specific question that has an answer?

Comment: Voting to close as a "problem that can no longer be reproduced." Per [Op's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815774/cannot-find-toupper-in-system/55816906?noredirect=1#comment98338949_55816906), OP fixed the problem by rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your project.  Try the following steps:

Step 1: Open an new instance of Visual Studio 2017.
Step 2: In the top menu, select File->New Project
Step 3: Select Visual C#->.Net Standard.  Create a new project.
Step 4: Replace the contents of your csproj file with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Step 5: Copy-paste the below code into the generated "Class1.cs" file:

```
namespace NetStandardTest
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public static string ToUpperTest(string str1)
        {
            string str2 = str1.ToUpper();
            return str2;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, your library should compile.  If it does not compile, please update your question with the corresponding error message.

Comment: Nitpick: Visual Studio 2019 was [released on April 02, 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes) and is not in preview anymore.

Comment: @JustinLessard: This isn't the first time I've accidentally claimed it was still in preview.  I keep finding stuff like https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/ and forgetting that such pages don't magically get fixed when preview ends.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studios and my computer fixed the issue, not sure why or how. Thanks for your help